# Django complex filter with two tables

Tags: python, django

I am in need of some help. I am struggling to figure this out.
I have two models

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    channel = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.order_id)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'orders'

class OrderPaymentMethods(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    payment_type = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
    fk_order = models.ForeignKey('Orders', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'order_payment_methods'
```

My goal is to count the number of orders that have a `OrderPaymentMethods` specific `payment_type`
Example:

```
orders = Orders.object.filter(Q(channel="Green_House"))
method_money = orders.filter(payment_methods = "credit").count()
```

How can I get the count based on the orders that were filtered?
Thank You

Comment: Use the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/):  `Oders.object.filter(orderpaymentmethods_set__payment_type="bar")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `Q` nor separating such query. You need to use relation lookup:

```
Orders.object.filter(channel="Green_House", orderpaymentmethods_set__payment_type="credit").count()
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one more question, when do you recommend the use of `Q`?

Comment: @BrunoP for much more complex queries or queries that you build in few places:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects